# Github API: List all repos(internal included) from a Github org using API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to list all the repos(public, internal) within the org that I am the owner of using the below command.

`$orgRepos = Invoke-WebRequest -H $headers -Uri "https://api.github.com/orgs/{$orgName}/repos"`

There are about 2 public repos and 10+ internal repos but the above command is listing out **only** the 2 public repos. I went through the documentation and tried all the options as suggested [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos) with `type` and `per_page` but nothing seems to help. For headers, I created it using my PAT by giving access to all the permissions.

```
$headers = @{
      Authorization = "Basic $($token)"
      Accept = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
}
```

How do I get to list out the internal repositories?

Comment: When you write internal repositories, do you mean private repositories or internal repositories of GitHub Enterprise?

Comment: It's internal repositories that I am looking for here

Comment: So you want the [internal repositories from a GitHub **enterprise instance**](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-repository-visibility)?

Comment: yes, in particular, I was looking for an API. this is fixed now by changing the header as posted below. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the header. Replacing "basic" with "token" helped solve the issue.

```
$headers = @{
      Authorization = "token $($token)"
      Accept = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
}
```

Thanks to the GH support community here.
https://github.community/t/list-all-repos-internal-included-from-a-github-org-using-api/177130/8